# Mangrove Jack Cider benefit from aging?

Tags: cider, aging

I have found that Mangrove Jack's Cider kits are quick for a summer drink and satisfies the family and friends with gluten issues. I just fermented another batch and don't have a keg available right now (yes, I know buy another) So, I racked it into a 6 gallon carboy, which got me wondering will aging it a bit will do anything beneficial as far a taste and quality? If so, how long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the one time I tried Mangrove Jack's, the "fresh" bottles all had a farm taste and smell, but the one I saved, for a few months, in the fridge, did get better with age. The flavour became smoother and I liked it. Next time I do it, I'll let everything age for a while.

Of course, this is just my experience, and mileage may vary...

Comment: My current keg of cider is down to it's last gallon or two and is definitely smoother then when first kegged, there is something to this aging thing.

Answer (score 0):

All ciders should go through conditioning (aging) for the fruit aroma and perceived sweetness to really come through. (Also if your cider is strong in Alcohol, the aging will reduce the "hot" alcohol feel.

> **I recommend 1 year in secondary, or in bottles/barrel.**

I recommend conditioning the cider *not* in plastic, but in glass bottles, or glass fermenters. Plastic "breathes" and may oxygenate your cider.

Good luck!